# Retrieve SAML assertion through JavaScript to pass to a Lambda function

Tags: javascript, saml, saml-2.0

I am currently working on building an https website using basic html and javascript which requires SAML 2.0 authentication for its users. I have a use case where I need to pass the SAML assertion for authenticated users to a Lambda function. I have the users set up through an identity provider via SAML 2.0. I am also able to check the SAML assertion in Network activity when I log in to the identity provider using my credentials. However, I am not sure how to retrieve this SAML assertion programmatically through javascript so that I can pass it to a Lambda function as a parameter. Can someone help me with understanding how this can be set up?